# merge 2 select with limit offset without relation SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to merge 2 select from 2 table with limit, offset like this.

```
table users
id | name | createdAt
1    John   2019-04-03
2    Smith  2019-04-04
3    Bob    2019-04-05
4    Anny   2019-04-06
5    Phon   2019-04-07


table books
id | title | author_id | createdAt
1     ABC        8       2019-04-03
2     XYZ        9       2019-04-06
```

I try to write the union query but not working

```
select users.id, users.name, null as bookTitle 
from users 
union select null, null, books.title 
from books
order by users.createdAt, books.createdAt
limit 4;
```

the result should be

```
id | name | bookTitle | createdAt
1    John     null      2019-04-03
null null     ABC       2019-04-03
2    Smith    null      2019-04-04
3    Bob      null      2019-04-05
```

I use sequelize.js to build the query by ORM.
Or do I have to write at sequelize and use FindAll from 2 table and merge them together.

Comment: Why some records (id = 4 and 5 from `users` and id = 2 from `books`) are skipped whereas all another are selected? Specify used limiting (and ordering! limit without ordering makes no sense) for each table

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the two portions of the union in parentheses, as tuples:

```
(SELECT users.id, users.name, NULL AS bookTitle FROM users)
UNION
(SELECT NULL, NULL, title FROM books ORDER BY createdAt LIMIT 4);
```

I also notice that your second query is referring to the `books` table in the `ORDER BY` clause.  This doesn't make any sense, because `books` is not part of that query.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is

```
(select from first table with its own ordering and limitation)
UNION ALL
(select from second table with its own ordering and limitation)
ORDER BY final_ordering
LIMIT final_limitation
```

Each separate subquery must have the same fieldset - both in fields count and in datatypes for each field by its physical posession.

If the value for such field exists in both tables (like `created_at` in a question) then this field is present in both subqueries. If the value for a field exists in one table only then `NULL` or some constant literal (for example, `'absent'` for string type or `0` for numeric field) is placed to its physical posession in another subquery.

If limitation in any part is used, then the ordering in this part must be used too. If a limitation in some subquery is not used then the ordering in it makes no sense and may be skipped too. Rather than final ordering - it makes sense even when final limitation is not used.

Pay attention - if ordering/limitation is used in a subquery then this subquery MUST be wrapped with parenthesis. If no ordering/limitation is used then the parenthesis are optional - but I'd recommend use it in any case.